# Draw circle with hole by using MKOverlayRenderer does not work well

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlaypathrenderer

I'd like to draw circle with hole (like donut) on mapview.
my code is here.

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CG    ContextRef)context {

WPCircleOverlay * circleOverlay = self.overlay;

CGPoint centerPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:MKMapPointForCoordinate(circleOverlay.coordinate)];

CGFloat innerRadius = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(circleOverlay.coordinate.latitude) * circleOverlay.innerRadius;
CGFloat outerRadius = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(circleOverlay.coordinate.latitude) * circleOverlay.outerRadius;
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

//CGPathMoveToPoint(path, ...);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, outerRadius, 0, 2 * M_PI, true);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

// Add the inner arc to the path (later used to substract the inner area)
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, innerRadius, 0, 2 * M_PI, true);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

// Add the path to the context
CGContextAddPath(context, path);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.fillColor.CGColor);
CGContextEOFillPath(context);

CGPathRelease(path);
```

It works well in simulator, but on device it doesn't.

On device, outer circle is filled with color, and inner circle wasn't clipped.
How can I modify my code to work well on device?

Comment: Might want to add screen shots to show difference.

Comment: I fixed it. Maybe CGPathAddArc and CGContextEOFillPath could not use simultaneously. (I updated my code.)

Comment: A better way to show this might be to answer your own question. That is perfectly legal (ask a question, answer it yourself) and a good use of the stack overflow format.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by using CGContextAddEllipseInRect method instead of CGContextAddArc.

```
WPCircleOverlay * circleOverlay = self.overlay;

CGRect rectForMapRect = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];
CGPoint centerPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:MKMapPointForCoordinate(circleOverlay.coordinate)];

CGFloat innerRadius = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(circleOverlay.coordinate.latitude) * circleOverlay.innerRadius;
CGFloat outerRadius = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(circleOverlay.coordinate.latitude) * circleOverlay.outerRadius;

CGRect innerRect = CGRectMake(centerPoint.x - innerRadius, centerPoint.y - innerRadius, innerRadius * 2.0, innerRadius * 2.0);
CGRect outerRect = CGRectMake(centerPoint.x - outerRadius, centerPoint.y - outerRadius, outerRadius * 2.0, outerRadius * 2.0);

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rectForMapRect, outerRect)) {

    CGContextAddRect(context, rectForMapRect);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, outerRect);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, innerRect);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextEOClip(context);

    UIColor * color = [self.fillColor copy];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, outerRect);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Comment: Upvoted your question, for being interesting and clearly presented, and your answer, because you solved your own problem.